# Why Am I Getting a Validation Failed Error When Setting Up a Cloud Storage Container Oracle Database Cloud Service?

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I just signed up for a trial of Oracle Cloud, and am going through the tutorial for the Java Service, but to do that I have to set up the DB Cloud service. However, when I set up the Cloud Service Container I get the following error.

```
Error: Creation of cloud storage container, https://us1.storage.oraclecloud.com/v1/Storage–Blanks/myFirstContainer, failed: [ERROR] InvalidStorageConnection: cannot authenticate:
```

I saw that some people got post it by setting a replication policy within Cloud Storage. I tried that, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

To setup the database as a service, one needs to provide a valid Oracle Storage service container, your error indicates that the container connection information is not set correctly. You may want to check whether:

1. the provided container path complies to the required format;
2. you provided the correct username/password. To verify, either use the same credentials to login to the My Services page; or construct an AUTH call to storage to see if it returns the auth token, see details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas/storage-cloud/cssto/authenticating-access-when-using-rest-api.html).